# Thms on Dynamical Systems: Cont. functions on Compact Spaces (sources)

Tags: general-topology, continuity, dynamical-systems, compactness

I've recently started taking a discrete-time dynamical systems perspective on a topic. I've been able to introduce a reasonable metric on a set, obtaining a compact space. Under that metric, a nice class of functions are continuous.

I'm now searching for theory that will allow me to get a better understanding of the behaviour of the class functions.

**Can you recommend sources / lists of results that apply to continuous maps on compact spaces?**

I know of Conley's Decomposition Theorem and am looking for similar, including both more basic and advanced. As this is not my area of expertise, any references would be appreciated.

Comment: From my own experience, this fact might be quite useful in this context: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism. IMO, you can compile this list from several non-introduction books on general topology.